# QuickTime Plugin not sending cookies

Tags: plugins, quicktime

The application has a page with thumbnails.  Clicking on a thumbnail calls the SetURL() javascript function on the player object.

In Safari on Windows, about 75% of the time, the plugin makes the request, sends the cookie, and life is good.  The other 25% of the time, it fails to load at all half the time and when it does load, it won't loop.  When it fails, we see the following requests:

127.0.0.1 - [20/May/2009:11:15:19 -0400] "GET /full/?id=1 HTTP/1.1" 302 - "-" 80 7542 0 QuickTime/7.6 (qtver=7.6;os=Windows NT 5.1Service Pack 3)
127.0.0.1 - [20/May/2009:11:15:19 -0400] "GET /denied/ HTTP/1.1" 200 3385 "-" 80 9050 0 QuickTime/7.6 (qtver=7.6;os=Windows NT 5.1Service Pack 3)
127.0.0.1 - [20/May/2009:11:15:20 -0400] "GET /full/?id=1 HTTP/1.1" 200 2639638 "-" 80 2005787 2 Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US) AppleWebKit/525.27.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/3.2.1 Safari/525.27.1

The first request comes directly from the plugin and the request does not contain the session cookie, so the app redirects it to the "unauthorized access" page.  We then see the plugin make the request to the redirected page.  Then we see the same initial request from the browser itself.  That request contains the cookie so it succeeds.  About half the time, the movie plays, the other half it doesn't.

As I said, if we have 10 thumbnails on a page, everything works fine for at least 7 of them so we know the plugin is actually loaded.  There are no javascript errors.

I have seen similar behavior in IE, but have not been able to reproduce it consistantly.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

On our development servers we password protect the sites at the server level (via htpasswd).

In Firefox, the first time the SetURL() was called for a new movie, the browser would wait and pop the password alert, regardless of whether or not it was "remembered" in the keychain. Once the credentials were sent, then QuickTime would load the movie.

In Chrome, it was remembered.

IE still won't swap the file. Downloading Charles Proxy now...